# List of SAP Ports

Tags: server, client, hana, netweaver

What are the ports that I have to add to my firewall in order to use SAP Client along with SAP Server?

Was the port number from Year 2009 still needed to this Years SAP?

Can someone give me a link or list of ports that are needed.

Comment: Please do your own research. If your face any issue, then come to SO with your error.

Comment: which client ? which server ? SAP GUI ? With or without SAPROUTER ?  sap gui on abap stack is 32xx 33xx 36xx.  The are som many clients and so many servers and many are freely configurable.

Comment: SAP is a software company. Which SAP software do you mean? Based on current answers, proposing to re-tag to NetWeaver and HANA.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. See sap documentation:

http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73ehp1/helpdata/en/4e/c26cdc58e968b9e10000000a42189e/frameset.htm

For the sap client = SAPGUI the dispatcher is relevant:
Port 32<NN> where NN = instance number of the application server/dispatcher.

SAP BIW Business explorer also opens an RFC connection which requires 
port 33<NN>

Answer (score 0):

See "TCP/IP Ports of All SAP Products" at https://help.sap.com/docs/Security/575a9f0e56f34c6e8138439eefc32b16/616a3c0b1cc748238de9c0341b15c63c.html
Traditional RFC over CPIC communication between SAP client and server has not changed. New means of communication include REST over HTTP(S) *if* the specific SAP system has those enabled. It requires SAP admin to expose specific SAP business entities one by one for REST access.